# Wrong start date for current job

Tags: background-check, employment

My mom offered to update my resume for me since I don't have a computer, after having my interview, getting a contingent job offer, I'm waiting for my background and drug test to come back. I know I will pass everything but my worry is looking over everything, my mother must have misunderstood the start date I told her for my current job. I know I should have looked it over but I didn't think to because she's always good with these things. What should I do? Should I say something? Or wait and see if it comes up?

Comment: Why did you put your start date on your resume? Did you gave them that resume during the interview?

Comment: I did the month and year. I didn't notice until after my interview and after the contingent job offer so I'm waiting on the background check and drug test and wondering if I have anything to worry about.

Comment: Sorry I still dont get it. The date that was misplaced indicated the day you are willing to start working with them? This I consider is not to be added in something like your resume, but rather told on interview... anyways it is up to the company to decide what day they want you to start. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The month and day that was written wrong is from my current job that I've been working at, the job that I applied for that I'm waiting for the background check and drug test results from doesn't have a training class until September 5th. Does that make a little more sense? Not meaning for it to be confusing

Comment: Ok, now I get it I think. You misplaced the date (therefore work time) of your soon-to-be old job, so the actual time you worked there is nor correctly reflected

Comment: Correct, I'm already waiting on the background check to come back so I'm not sure if I should try to contact them to tell them or to wait and see if it comes up. I really need this new job and this is the last step, I've already been offered the job, obviously as long as I pass both background and drug test. I don't do drugs, never been arrested, etc. so this is the only thing worrying me

Comment: Ok, posting an answer with some options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on the severity and importance of that *erratum*.

If it changed your total time in that company by a significant amount (say you worked there for 1 year but the date actually says 1.5 years) I would write an email to them explaining the misplacement along with the corrected version of your Resume. Nothing too complicated, just point out the change and politely apologize.

If the date was just some days or something not *so* significant not writing the email should be ok.

However, personally I would write the email no matter how minor the change was, so there is no chance for a misunderstanding or something undesired. Either way, don't forget to update your resume for future interviews.